# Openfire: How can I know which users stored in the server are my device contacts?

Tags: android, openfire, asmack

I'm developing a simple chat for Android. I'm reading about Openfire ante asmack API. Obviously the user should see only the contacts stored in his device, so: How can I know which contacts stored in the server are my device contacts? or, how can I assign to a contact the contacts that he have in his device? I've see that it can be done in the Admin console, but by code? It's the last thing I need to know to start developing it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Create the configuration for this new connection
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("jabber.org", 5222);
config.setCompressionEnabled(true);
config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);

Connection connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
// Connect to the server
connection.connect();
// Log into the server
connection.login("danilodeveloper", "password", "SomeResource");
// getting the Openfire contacts that danilodeveloper has
Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
// the contacts
Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
```

With the entries (for example entrie.getUser()), you can compare the Openfire contacts with the device contacts.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks danilo, but, what parameter can I use to compare Operfire contacts and device contacts? I mean, contacts in Openfire don't have telephone number, and user names may not be the same.

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm using the internal BD of Openfire. Shall I use MySQL, maybe?

Comment: hi @luis, you can store the phone number on Openfire via Smack API (I don't remember what is the method, but it should be simple) and you can retrieve using [link]http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/openfire/user/User.html (getProperty method).

Comment: @luis, about MySQL, you should use when you application go into production, you will best performance and you can use cluster. Use the internal BD for development fase.

Comment: @danilodeveloper I tried your answer, but it is returning the list of friends of mine. what if i want to check my contacts that are not added in my roster. like whatsapp contacts. whatsapp detects which contact has whatsapp app and if yes we are able to send msg him/her. else invite,